# Filename too long sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I am getting an error saying I have a file that is too long in sbt.

```
 [info] Compiling 29 Scala sources to /home/chris/dev/suredbits-core/target/scala-2.11/classes...
    [error] File name too long
    [error] one error found
    [error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
    [error] Total time: 7 s, completed Feb 17, 2015 8:10:25 AM
```

How do I find out which file is too long so I can shorten the filename? I have added the compiler flag `-Xmax-classfile-name` and set it to 254.

Comment: In my case, this happened in a play template where I had two nested 'defining'. Using a tuple in a single 'defining' did the trick.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem

```
mkdir /tmp/myproject-target
cd ~/workspace/myproject
rm -rf target
ln -s /tmp/myproject-target target
```

Comment: This has the downside that the compiler output (easily reversible) no longer resides on an encrypted file system.

Answer (score 55):

If your `/home` is an encrypted file system (e.g. LUKS), you might run into this issue.

Setting `max-classfile-name` to 254 is the default (or it might be 255) - so you're not reducing it much. You should probably be considering something closer to a max length of 70 - 100. You can set it for all your projects by creating `~/.sbt/0.13/local.sbt` with the scalac override:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Xmax-classfile-name","78")
```

Comment: Had this problem compiling inside a docker container. That fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Brett. I used your solution too and it worked realy great for a short time. But sadly the com.typesafe.slick dependency of slick 3.0.0 contains a file in it's jar which has a file with a length of 73 signs (including the path within the jar). The result is that a extremely strange NoClassDefFoundError occours. I correct the 72 from your suggestion into a 100 for now but thats not realy a good solution.

Comment: @Brett please edit your answer and put 100 instead of 72 for those who use Slick as Niels said.

Comment: Amir / Niels - `72` was used as an indicative answer, not a hard and final solution - the write up before the code sample gives the background for the error and the approach covers using a range between 70 and 100 - so adjust for individual use-cases. Someone using Docker with LUKS with a long project path may need to adjust downwards to 70 while others may need to adjust upwards towards the 80's.  Would not say that the exact example I provided for all use-cases, however, the approach may help you solve your issue. I have however adjusted my answer to cater for Slick users.

Comment: `scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Xmax-classfile-name","128")` worked for me

Comment: Beware that this will break binary compatibility for dependencies with class files longer than 78 characters. Drop the limit sparingly. If 240 works, use that instead.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this problem in IntelliJ Ultimate 2016.1.2 (which resembles Intellij 14). I solved it by setting:

```
-Xmax-classfile-name 78
```

In **File > Settings... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Scala Compiler > Additional Compiler Options**.

**NOTE:** there is a *space* between the option name and its value ("78"), not an equals sign.

Comment: In my case, on that page I had the Default compiler options for each module, and separate SBT profiles. This solution worked after I added the option under an SBT profile, NOT the Default one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in *; do {
        echo -m "$file" | wc -m;
        echo "$file"
}
done
```

Running this in your src/main/scala directory should show you which files have a name with more than 254 chars. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: This doesn't work, I think what is happening is that there is a .class file being generated that is longer than 255 characters, but I cannot tell which one because compilation fails before that class file is generated

Answer (score 0):

- Setting the file length limits might be unsafe, I could not find any official documentation that this solution is safe.
- Using un-encrypted directory is not safe.

I want to offer a different approach:

- install [veracrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html) ([in ubuntu with apt](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-veracrypt-ubuntu-16-04-16-10))
- create a non-encrypted directory (outside the encrypted user home dir)
- create a veracrypt file container in the new directory
- mount the container in

---

- sbt works fine even if the mount point is in the encrypted directory)
- It is possible to create the container with a complex password and mount on login

  veracrypt -t --pim=0 --protect-hidden=no -k ""  -p $PASSWORD $ENCRYPTED_CONTAINER $MOUNT_DIR