# PlayFramework Slick NoSuchMethodError

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, slick

Im having strange problem while using new slick version with mysql:

```
[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: slick.driver.JdbcProfile$API.streamableQueryActionExtensionMethods(Lslick/lifted/Query;)Lslick/profile/BasicActionComp$$$$6aa48549c0a7603df1fa229cf7177493$$$$sionMethodsImpl;]
```

in my application.conf:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false"
slick.dbs.default.db.user = "root"
slick.dbs.default.db.password = ""
```

and code:

throwing exception:

```
 Await.result(db.run(table.result), Duration.Inf)
```

evolutions did good job, tables created etc. But here I have such nasty error ;/

My built.sbt:

```
name := """bettor"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val utilsDeps = Seq("joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.4",
  "com.github.tototoshi" %% "slick-joda-mapper" % "2.2.0",
  "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.8.1")

val dbsDeps = Seq("com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0",
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "2.0.0",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "6.0.2")

val jsonDeps = Seq("org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.4.0",
  "org.jsoup" % "jsoup" % "1.9.2")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  ws,
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test
) ++ utilsDeps ++ dbsDeps ++ jsonDeps

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue ?

even using this template without changing anything I have same error :(

[play-slick-mysql](https://github.com/taiwotman/play-slick-mysql)

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I used `Seq("-Xmax-classfile-name","78")` feature suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32862972/1432640 without reading the comments (this case was mentioned there), and was struggling with the error for 4+ hours. Nightmare is over! Smeagol is free!

Answer (score 0):

Heh, adding to build sbt:

```
scalacOptions := Seq("-feature")
```

resolved problem.