# Installing SBT in Linux - Error: File name too long

Tags: linux, scala, sbt

I am trying to install SBT following the instructions mentioned in:
[here](http://www.nodalpoint.com/development-and-deployment-of-spark-applications-with-scala-eclipse-and-sbt-part-1-installation-configuration/)

But I am getting an error while running command:

```
wget https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/native-packages/sbt/0.13.8/sbt-0.13.8.tgz
```

The error is:

> --2016-08-16 11:39:16--  https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/native-packages/sbt/0.13.8/sbt-0.13.8.tgz
>   Resolving dl.bintray.com... 108.168.243.150, 75.126.118.188 Connecting
>   to dl.bintray.com|108.168.243.150|:443... connected. HTTP request
>   sent, awaiting response... 302 Location:
>   [https://akamai.bintray.com/15/155d6ff3bc178745ad4f951b74792b257ed14105?**gda**=exp=1471366276~hmac=1332caeed34aa8465829ba9f19379685c23e33ede86be8d2b10e47ca4752f8f0&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22sbt-0.13.8.tgz%22&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream&requestInfo=U2FsdGVkX19rkawieFWSsqtapFvvLhwJbzqc8qYcoelvh1%2BUW9ffT9Q4RIJPf%2B2WqkegCpNt2tOXFO9VlWuoGzk1Wdii9dr2HpibwrTfZ92pO8iqdjNbL%2BDzZTYiC826](https://akamai.bintray.com/15/155d6ff3bc178745ad4f951b74792b257ed14105?__gda__=exp=1471366276~hmac=1332caeed34aa8465829ba9f19379685c23e33ede86be8d2b10e47ca4752f8f0&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22sbt-0.13.8.tgz%22&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream&requestInfo=U2FsdGVkX19rkawieFWSsqtapFvvLhwJbzqc8qYcoelvh1%2BUW9ffT9Q4RIJPf%2B2WqkegCpNt2tOXFO9VlWuoGzk1Wdii9dr2HpibwrTfZ92pO8iqdjNbL%2BDzZTYiC826)
>   [following]
>   --2016-08-16 11:39:16--  [https://akamai.bintray.com/15/155d6ff3bc178745ad4f951b74792b257ed14105?**gda**=exp=1471366276~hmac=1332caeed34aa8465829ba9f19379685c23e33ede86be8d2b10e47ca4752f8f0&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22sbt-0.13.8.tgz%22&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream&requestInfo=U2FsdGVkX19rkawieFWSsqtapFvvLhwJbzqc8qYcoelvh1%2BUW9ffT9Q4RIJPf%2B2WqkegCpNt2tOXFO9VlWuoGzk1Wdii9dr2HpibwrTfZ92pO8iqdjNbL%2BDzZTYiC826](https://akamai.bintray.com/15/155d6ff3bc178745ad4f951b74792b257ed14105?__gda__=exp=1471366276~hmac=1332caeed34aa8465829ba9f19379685c23e33ede86be8d2b10e47ca4752f8f0&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22sbt-0.13.8.tgz%22&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream&requestInfo=U2FsdGVkX19rkawieFWSsqtapFvvLhwJbzqc8qYcoelvh1%2BUW9ffT9Q4RIJPf%2B2WqkegCpNt2tOXFO9VlWuoGzk1Wdii9dr2HpibwrTfZ92pO8iqdjNbL%2BDzZTYiC826)
>   Resolving akamai.bintray.com... 23.193.25.35 Connecting to
>   akamai.bintray.com|23.193.25.35|:443... connected. HTTP request sent,
>   awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 1059183 (1.0M)
>   [application/octet-stream]
>   155d6ff3bc178745ad4f951b74792b257ed14105?**gda**=exp=1471366276~hmac=1332caeed34aa8465829ba9f19379685c23e33ede86be8d2b10e47ca4752f8f0&response-content-disposition=attachment;filename="sbt-0.13.8.tgz"&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream&requestInfo=U2FsdGVkX19rkawieFWSsqtapFvvLhwJbzqc8qYcoelvh1+UW9ffT9Q4RIJPf+2WqkegCpNt2tOXFO9VlWuoGzk1Wdii9dr2HpibwrTfZ92pO8iqdjNbL+DzZTYiC826:
>   File name too long
>
> Cannot write to
>   “155d6ff3bc178745ad4f951b74792b257ed14105?**gda**=exp=1471366276~hmac=1332caeed34aa8465829ba9f19379685c23e33ede86be8d2b10e47ca4752f8f0&response-content-disposition=attachment;filename="sbt-0.13.8.tgz"&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream&requestInfo=U2FsdGVkX19rkawieFWSsqtapFvvLhwJbzqc8qYcoelvh1+UW9ffT9Q4RIJPf+2WqkegCpNt2tOXFO9VlWuoGzk1Wdii9dr2HpibwrTfZ92pO8iqdjNbL+DzZTYiC826”
>   (Success).

I referred [StackOverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565837/filename-too-long-sbt) with similar issue but I am not able to figure out what is the problem.

Comment: How about this `wget -o file.gz https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/native-packages/sbt/0.13.8/sbt-0.13.8.tgz` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's really an issue with the filename. I was able to use that same command without a problem. If the filename was an issue, you could always use this to save it as a different filename:

`wget -O newname.tgz https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/native-packages/sbt/0.13.8/sbt-0.13.8.tgz`

The other option is to use bitly and get a URL if the URL is just too long.

But it could be a space issue. Do you have enough disk space? Check with `df -h` to see your available space.