# Getting File name too long when running tests on circleci

Tags: scala, build, scalatest, circleci, scalacheck

Im building my project with circleci 2 and in my test coverage im getting a weird error:

```
[info] Compiling 5 Scala sources to /root/build/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
[error] /root/build/test/myApplication/SomeGeneratorNameGen.scala:40: File name too long
[error] This can happen on some encrypted or legacy file systems.  Please see SI-3623 for more details.
[error]     employeeName <- Gen.numStr
[error]                  ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file length is

```
printf /root/build/test/myApplication/AmountPerExpTypeGen.scala | wc -c
      56

$ printf /root/build/test/myApplication/ | wc -c
      31
```

Based on the most of the references, you might want to increase the length using scalac options.

eg.

```
"-Xmax-classfile-name", "242"
```

### Releated links

https://discuss.circleci.com/t/scala-sbt-assembly-does-not-work/10499/10

[Filename too long sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28565837/432903)

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/issues/69#issuecomment-14176243

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/wtD6vgdiy6g

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3623