# Kotlin: On linux with encrypted home: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File name too long)

Tags: java, kotlin

Under an encrypted linux home directory my Kotlin build (using maven) is failing with a "java.io.FileNotFoundException (File name too long)".

The filename looks something like this, and is 298 characters long:

```
/home/niel/projects/project/bla/.../bla/.../bla/SomeTest$test name with spaces$1.class
```

The test looks something like this:

```
@Test
fun `test with nice descriptive name`() {
    // ...
}
```

---

`getconf NAME_MAX /` returns `255`, more than the `298` of the file name.

**Scala** has a way of dealing with this using the [`max-classfile-name`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32862972/297331) option.

Is there a solution for this in Kotlin?

Comment: Is the method name ending up as the class file name?

Answer (score 2):

I've been bumping my head on the same issue. The problem is exacerbated (occurs primarily?) when using lambdas inside of such descriptively named test methods.

In my case I'm using ecryptfs with encrypted filenames on top of ext4. Given the payload and padding that's added to the start of the filename by ecryptfs, it seems that [~140 bytes is the usable maximum filename length](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32795/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-filename-and-folder-size-with-ecryptfs).

I don't know of a mechanism in Kotlin for working around this problem, but if you're using JUnit 5 you could make use of the [@DisplayName](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/DisplayName.html) annotation for your more verbose test names.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `@JvmName` annotation to rename your test I believe. See the [reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#handling-signature-clashes-with-jvmname) and the [api](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-name/)

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried it and it still tries to create the class file with the original name.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when the volume your doing the test on is not encrypted ? It seems like the first logical thing to do since home volume encryption has special characteristics [eCrypt details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32795/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-filename-and-folder-size-with-ecryptfs)

Comment: Yes, it runs fine on my colleague who has an unencrypted disk's machine.